# stream byte arrays to a video using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, video-conversion, c#

This is what I am trying to do:

I receive jpegs from an IP camera.  If motion is detected I want to upload the jpeg still shot to my server.

To save on bandwidth I save each jpeg to a file on my hard drive and I give it a sequence number.

I then use ffmpeg to create a AVI file.

I then load this AVI to a memory stream and upload the byte array of that stream to my server using WCF.

As each jpeg is saved to the hard drive there is an overhead of doing so.
If it was possible to skip this step and stream these jpegs directly as an input to an avi file using ffmpeg then I will save time and memory.

This may be easy (I do not know if it is) on non-windows platforms and/or using C++ but I am using C# on Windows 7.

I can add the code I use to convert images to an avi file if requested and people think it is pertinent?